# How to split image into equal parts and get average hex color of each part?

Tags: bash, image, imagemagick

I was wondering if it's possible to split image into 60 equal vertical parts (stripes) and get the average hex color of each of them.

A sample image could be this rainbow which is not easy to create dynamically/programatically:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can do that much more simply and without creating files and running tens of external processes like `tail`, `cut` and `magick`.

If you use the following syntax, you will get your 60 images in a stack inside a single invocation of **ImageMagick**:

```
magick image.png -crop 60x1@ ...
```

You can then average all 60 images down to 1x1 pixel each and print in hex:

```
magick image.png -crop 60x1@ -scale 1x1\! -format "%s: #%[hex:s]\n" info:  > colors.txt
```

Comment: Such a nice concise solution, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Given the image you have, which has a different color for each column, you can do that in Imagemagick by getting the unique-colors, then average those. The -scale 1x1! does the averaging.

```
magick image.png -unique-colors -scale 1x1! -format "%[hex:u.p]\n" info:

EFC98EFD
```

**ADDITION**

If we assume that all pixels in each column have the same color, it is probably easier to just do:

```
magick image.png -scale 1x1! -format "%[hex:u.p]\n" info:

F4C08CFF
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `imagemagick` to split image into equal parts and then read its average colors using simple bash script

To split image into width/60 parts where width is 500 px. (100/60 = 1.666%)

```bash
convert input.png -crop 1.67%x100% +repage output%d.png
```

It will generate a bunch of files enumerated from output1.png to output62.png due to the rounding of the image to the nearest pixel. You can probably just ignore 2 random images to get 60 of them.

Then to read the color of the image you can read it in a loop

```bash
for i in {1..62}; do
    file="output${i}.png"

    # Use ImageMagick to get the average color
    color=$(convert "$file" -resize 1x1 txt:- | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 4)

    # Append the color to the output file
    echo "$color" >>colors.txt
done
```

Make sure to `chmod +x colors.sh` in order to be able to execute the bash script via `./colors.sh`

The resulting file will include all the colors

```
#F7919BFF
#F7929AFF
#F79399FF
#F79498FF
#F79597FF
#F79696FF
#F79794FF
#F79893FF
#F79992FF
#F79A91FF
#F79B90FF
#F79C8FFF
#F79D8DFF
#F79F8CFF
#F7A08BFF
#F7A18AFF
#F7A289FF
#F7A388FF
#F7A486FF
#F7A686FF
#F7A886FF
#F7AA86FF
#F7AD86FF
#F7AF86FF
#F7B186FF
#F7B386FF
#F7B686FF
#F7B886FF
#F7BA86FF
#F7BC86FF
#F7BF86FF
#F7C186FF
#F7C386FF
#F7C686FF
#F7C886FF
#F7CA86FF
#F7CC86FF
#F7CF86FF
#F7D186FF
#F7D386FF
#F6D587FF
#F6D787FF
#F6D987FF
#F5DB87FF
#F5DD88FF
#F5DE88FF
#F4E088FF
#F4E288FF
#F4E489FF
#F3E689FF
#F3E889FF
#F2EA89FF
#F2EC8AFF
#F2EE8AFF
#F1F08AFF
#F1F28AFF
#F1F48BFF
#F0F68BFF
#EDF78DFF
#DCF596FF
#CAF29FFF
#BDF1A6FA
```

Note that alpha channel is included as the last part of the hex color (FF)